# chrome extension refuses to load Google analytics

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-analytics

I've followed countless stackoverflow tutorials specifying how to install Google analytics correctly for your chrome extension but nothing has seemed to work me this far.

Right now I have the Google analytics tracking code inside of my main js file:

```
(function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
(i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
})(window,document,'script','https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXXXX-1', 'auto');
ga('set', 'checkProtocolTask', function(){}); 
ga('require', 'displayfeatures');
ga('send', 'pageview', '/override.html');
```

My `content_security_policy` looks like this:

```
"content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' https://query.yahooapis.com https://google-analytics.com; object-src 'self'"
```

When I run it inside of my local extension the error I get is:

> Refused to load the script 'https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' https://query.yahooapis.com https://google-analytics.com".

I've even tried downloading the analytics.js file and using that inside of a `content_script` but that didn't work either... Any ideas? I think I've looked at every stackoverflow questions there is about Google analytics inside of chrome extension and none have seemed to work...

Comment: At least you are missing `www.` in front of `google-analytics.com` on your `content_security_policy`.

Comment: Wow. I just spent about 3 hours trying to get this to work and I was missing `www.` ... I don't know if I should feel happy or sad.

Comment: @rsanchez if you create an answer for this question I'll mark it as correct..

Comment: on a sidenote, you should give the UA code itself a  namespace to avoid conflicting with other instances of UA on webpages

Comment: You should actually add the ga code in your background page. Be a good citizen and avoid running code in other people sites if it can conflict with their code.